# Android java: Efficient bitmap animation allocation

Tags: java, android, bitmap, draw

I have 17 bitmaps of the same size that are frames of a character walking animation, and I want them to loop in my code.  I want to be able to use inBitmap since I am reusing the same bitmaps.  I have a few questions about doing this:

1. can I / should I cache the bitmaps, and if so how?
2. is there any more memory efficient way of doing this?

My code looks like this: (i am using a custom draw view)

onCreate:

```
        bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.walk0, bitmapOptions);
        aBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOptions.outWidth,
                bitmapOptions.outHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bitmapOptions.inBitmap = aBitmap;
        bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.walk0, bitmapOptions);
        ship = Bitmap.createBitmap(aBitmap, 0, 0, aBitmap.getWidth(), aBitmap.getHeight(), shipMatrix, true);
```

onDraw:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
shipRectf.right = ship.getWidth();
shipRectf.left = 0;
shipRectf.top = 0;
shipRectf.bottom = ship.getHeight();
canvas.drawBitmap(ship, null, shipRectf, null);
}
```

Animating:

```
Runnable walkData = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run(){
            try{    

                BitmapFactory.Options shipOptions = null;
                shipOptions = bitmapOptions;

                if(shipOptions != null){
                shipOptions.inBitmap = aBitmap;
                }
            if(walkAnim==true)
                {
                    walkNum = (walkNum + 1) % imageIDs.length;
                   //walknum = index, imageids = int[] {R.drawables}
                    aBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageIDs[walkNum], shipOptions);
                    ship = Bitmap.createBitmap(aBitmap, 0, 0, aBitmap.getWidth(), aBitmap.getHeight(), shipMatrix, true);
                                           invalidate();

                }
                if(walkAnim==false)
                {
                    walkNum = 0;
                    ship = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageIDs[walkNum], shipOptions);
                }


            handler3.postDelayed(this, 50);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    };
```

Comment: did you try animation drawable??

Comment: isn't that for imageviews?

Comment: yes it is for imageviews

Comment: What if I want 50 of the same animation on one screen?

Comment: animation drawable replaces a single imageview with multiple images in a specified ammount of time see the developer docs for more informaiton it is the preferred and easy way to show frame by frame animation

Comment: Is it possible to have some items on the screen drawn on a canvas and others being imageviews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading your bitmaps at runtime like that is going to end up being very slow.

What I do is load all my bitmaps when the game is created, and store them in an array. Then when you are drawing you just reference the bitmap array and get the correct image for the current frame. It uses more memory but that's always the trade-off for faster runtime.

Comment: couldn't you use inbitmap to load each bitmap?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how you mean. That would overwrite the previous bitmap, so you'd still have to reload from the resources when you want the next frame.